# game file to server

Tags: javascript, express

I am trying to test my breakout game on a local host server through Express.js.

How would I be able to connect my directory that contains the game to the local host server?

I've been using the text editor: `brackets`, which sets up the server for you, but I need to be able run the game without using brackets.

I have my directory: "Breakout" which contains "Index.html" and "Breakout.js"

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to use [express as a static server](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html), which using a node example app listening on port 8000 could look like

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static('./public'));
var server = app.listen(8000, function () {
     var host = server.address().address;
     var port = server.address().port;
     console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

After telling express where the public directory is located (here `public` in the same folder as the server script) copy the "breakout" folder into "public" (say using lowercase) and then navigate to it using "http://localhost:8000/breakout/".

Comment: Thank you so much! It was a tremendous help!